# Can I use eager and lazy loading at the same time?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a model class with lazy loading on. Until now I always used lazy loading, for example loading a single student with a collection of his courses.

If I want to load all the courses with the collection of all students who are enrolled, can I use the Include() method of eager loading on a property with lazy loading on? Are there any side effects?

```c#
[ForeignKey("Id")]
public virtual ICollection<Students> Students { get; set; }
```

```
public IQueryable<Students> GetCoursesWithAllStudents()
{
     return db.Courses.Include(c => c.Students);
}
```

Comment: No problems, no side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. `Include()` specifically does that, it *includes* related entities: it forces them to be loaded when normally they aren't. You might add `ThenInclude()` to go deeper down the relationship ladder, as it allows to load data related to the previously included entity. 
However, *the returned entity is the highest one in the ladder*, not the latest.
In the following example, an `IQueryable<Professors>` is returned, with the `Courses` entities loaded and, inside the `Courses`, the `Students`.

```
public IQueryable<Professors> GetCoursesWithAllStudents()
{
     return db.Professors.Include(professor => professor.Courses)
                         .ThenInclude(course => course.Students);
}
```